# Change Threading for Multiprocess

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

I have a code which starts many functions by `threading.Thread()` and inside functions it sends requests.

so as the result it works very slow with sending requests and I thought it would be ok with Multiprocess method instead but I am not sure.

the problem is that functions send many different requests so it would be difficult to replace it all for using asyncio, aiohttp or something like that.

so the main goal is to change code for it to send requests with normal speed in many threads and not be too complicated, because it is about 100 different request in it.

now code uses something like this to start threads:

```
import requests
import threading

def main(a,proxy,proxystr):
    requests.get()
    #do some
    requests.post()
    #do some2
    #etc

for kish in range(odnovrem_t):
    gf=threading.Thread(target=main,args=(kish,proxys,proxystr,))
    gf.start()
    alg.append(gf)
for i in alg:
    i.join()
```

Comment: What is the average round trip time (RTT) between the local and remote hosts? What happens in `#do some`, `#do some2` and `#etc`? What is "normal speed?" Performance optimization requires details and this question provides few. The actual http request is I/O-bound which implies using threads, and you can use _a lot_ of threads. I bet `#do some`... does some CPU-bound task which would imply processes, but you shouldn't use more processes than you have logical CPUs. Without further information, I suggest handling the requests with a thread pool and process the data with a process pool.

Comment: Is the difficulty in using an async library (like httpx, for example, that has a client with `requests`-like methods: https://www.python-httpx.org/async/) just in that the amount of code that would have to be replaced is very large? I think it's unlikely you'll be able to squeeze a whole lot more performance out of threads from the GIL, and this IO-bound task is a perfect use-case for async code in general which will benefit from the lack of the threading overhead

Comment: @MichaelRuth cpu is used for like 10% only

by normal speed I mead that usually the function would be done in avarage 30 seconds, but in multithreading it takes like 5 minutes to perform atleast 1 time the function.

I read out that it is because of using Threads and not other ways.

in #do some #do some2 are some requests and other data generated needed for usage

Comment: @vellista yeah the only problem is that it would be really complicated to change all the requests and functions it self to work with asyncio

Comment: Even a small CPU-bound task in a thread can create significant performance degradation while managing 100 threads. The simplest solution would be to change the model from threads to processes. It should help. Will it be enough? Maybe. Will it be optimal? Absolutely not. Still would be nice to have more information. This is hardly a [mre] inferring from the discussion.

Comment: What are `kish`, `proxys` and `proxystr`? They are undefined in the question.

Comment: `Kish` is an `int`, I see that. How about the other two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that `concurrent.futures.Executor`s are more user-friendly than `Process` and `Thread`, especially for long inputs. Even the docs prefer them. Try `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, it provides a `map()` function which has the same interface as the builtin.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from itertools import repeat
import os
import requests


def main(a,proxy,proxystr):
    requests.get()
    #do some
    requests.post()
    #do some2
    #etc

kish = range(odnovrem_t)
num_cpus = os.cpu_count()
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_cpus-1) as executor:
    results = executor.map(main, kish, repeat(proxys), repeat(proxystr))
```

There's no sense in creating a process pool with more processes than the total CPUs - 1. This is because we don't want more processes than the total CPUs, but must account for the main process.

For arguments, `kish` was each value in `range(odnovrem_t)` so we make it the generator here. I assume `proxys` is a `list` of `lists` of proxy parameters like username, password, hostname, etc. Lastly, I assume `proxystr` is a format string which interpolates the values in `proxys`. So, `kish` is an `int` unique to each call to `main()`, and `proxys` and `proxystr` are repeated for each call to `main()`.